# how to create nested tags using spark xml

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-xml

I am trying to write a df as a xml file. My problem is how can I perform group by in the xml output.

my input data as a csv file:

```
user_id|acnt_id|transaction|desc 
1      |1234|   012345| desc1
1      |1234|   102345| desc2
1      |5678|   123454| desc1
2      |1234|   345672| desc1
```

I am reading the csv file and writing back as a xml file, I want to know how can i specify the nested schema when writing the xml .

currently what i am able to get

```
<transactions>
  <transaction>
          <user_id>1</user_id>
          <acnt_id>1234</acnt_id>
          <transaction>012345</transaction>
          <desc>desc1</desc>
  </transaction>
  <transaction>
          <user_id>1</user_id>
          <acnt_id>1234</acnt_id>
          <transaction>102345</transaction>
          <desc>desc2</desc>
  </transaction>
  <transaction>
          <user_id>1</user_id>
          <acnt_id>5678</acnt_id>
          <transaction>123454</transaction>
          <desc>desc1</desc>
  </transaction>
  <transaction>
          <user_id>2</user_id>
          <acnt_id>1234</acnt_id>
          <transaction>345672</transaction>
          <desc>desc2</desc>
  </transaction>
</transactions>
```

Expected o/p

```
<transactions>
  <transaction>
          <user_id>1</user_id>
              <acnt_id>1234</acnt_id>
                  <transaction>012345</transaction>
                  <desc>desc1</desc>
                  <transaction>102345</transaction>
                  <desc>desc2</desc>
              <acnt_id>5678</acnt_id>
                  <transaction>123454</transaction>        
                  <desc>desc1</desc>
  </transaction>
  <transaction>
          <user_id>2</user_id>
            <acnt_id>1234</acnt_id>
              <transaction>345672</transaction>
              <desc>desc2</desc>
  </transaction>
</transactions>
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind getting your output from your data?

Comment: Hi @ShankarKoirala, I have updated the expected output. Basically i want to group by user_id and acnt_id and transaction

Comment: @ShankarKoirala any idea how can the expected o/p can be achived?

Comment: I don't know why you need output in such weird format. For this I think You have to write manually by creating tags as string and save as a text file. I don't see any other options.